# jquery else if statement using link clicks with json

Tags: jquery, json, click

hoping somebody can help me out with this.
I need to create a script that can store items in Json, then have links on the page when clicked shows what json object it is referring to. Im trying to do this with if else if statements and its not working. Im a bit lost. Heres the code ive done so far. it doesnt like the else if bit either.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var obj1 = {"user":"Shane", "age":28, "country": "Ireland"};
    var obj2 = {"user":"Louise", "age":26, "country": "Ireland"};
    var obj3 = {"user":"Jess", "age":28, "country": "Ireland"};
    var obj4 = {u1:obj1, u2:obj2, u3:obj3};

    $("a").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).hasClass("first"))
        {
            alert(obj1.user + " " + "was clicked");
        };
        else if ($(this).hasClass("second"))
        {
            alert(obj2.user + " " + "was clicked");
        };
    });

});
```

and in the html i just have

```
<body>

<a class="first" href="#">Product1</a><br>
<a class="second" href="#">Product2</a>

<p></p>


<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the semicolons after your blocks. Semicolons are there to denote the end of a `statement`, not the end of a `block`:

```
if ($(this).hasClass("first"))
{
    alert(obj1.user + " " + "was clicked");
}
else if ($(this).hasClass("second"))
{
    alert(obj2.user + " " + "was clicked");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error at the end of `if` block, remove the `;` before `else`

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass("first")){
        alert(obj1.user + " " + "was clicked");
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("second")){
        alert(obj2.user + " " + "was clicked");
    };
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UfXb7/)